# Calculate drawable width

Tags: android

I have a `Drawable` **only** in the hdpi folder (and can't be in others).

In my custom view, I want to calculate the `ImageView` width, in `onMeasure()`.

Code is :

```
myImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
```

But, depend on the device, the `IntrinsicWidth` is not the same and not egal to the real width.

This code :

```
Log.e(TAG, "icon width="+myImage.getWidth()+" // intrinsic width="+myImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
```

Print these results :

- On Nexus 4 : 180 // 187
- On Asus transformers : 320 // 187
- On Samsung S4 : 270 // 280

So, is there a way to get IntrinsicWidth equal to real width ?

Maybe with density ?

Comment: put it on drawable-nodpi folder otherwise it will be rescaled by the framework

Comment: It can't be moved... I have to find a way with image in hdpi folder

Comment: ok,  if it really can't be moved you have one option: create custom Resource class,  see how i did it here https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable/blob/master/PatchworkDrawableLibrary/src/org/pskink/patchworkdrawable/drawable/PatchworkDrawable.java see the class extending Resources at the very bottom

Answer (score 2):

While your Image in `hdpi` folder, Android will scale it (up or down) depending on on device density,
Put your Image in `nodpi` folder (`drawable-nodpi`) so Android will load the image with its original dimensions.

**Update**:
By knowing
0.75 - ldpi
1.0 - mdpi
1.5 - hdpi
2.0 - xhdpi
3.0 - xxhdpi
4.0 - xxxhdpi

And you know your image at `hdpi` folder so its 1.5 larger than the `mdpi`.

```
final float deviceDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int originalwidth = (int)((myImage.getWidth() * 1.5) / deviceDensity);
```

Comment: It can't be moved... I have to find a way with image in hdpi folder

Comment: why cant be moved? is your folder read-only :p. other wise why not just hard-coded your image width in your code, but when android load it, it will get scaled.

Comment: Because my boss don't want to :/

Comment: Then simply calculate the image width by getting the device density and multiply/divide it with the IntrinsicWidth

Comment: myImage.getWidth() = 0 in the onMeasure() method, I have to use myImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();